# International URL slugs and Google

Tags: seo, url, internationalization, url-slug

I'm working on an international web project and it includes languages like Russian.
What is the best practice for URL slugs? Should it also be in Russian alphabet?
Rather convert it to Latin? (example: https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-slugs/)

I know that both should work for Google. But from a user standpoint, if a language includes non-Latin characters, would a user use those characters in a search? Would Google recognize the word if it is converted to Latin? (E.g. *Реферат* vs. *riefierat*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an user looks for a keyword in Russian, Google will display results using that alphabet. Using the example you provided:

- Googling **Рефера́т**, look how it makes Рефера́т bold, but not it's equivalent in the latin alphabet.

  [image]
- Googling the other way around, it only highlight the relevant search, but not it transcription in Russian.

  [image]

The same happens in the URL, I think a Russian user would make more sense to look for words using the Cyrillic alphabet instead of the Latin one.